# Ext.data.Store getTotalCount alway returns 0

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have a problem getting total number of features (land parcels) from GeoExt.data.FeatureStore/Ext.data.Store which is populated from JSON retrieved using PHP. Total number is used as a condition to display either an error message (if no features are returned) or window containing search result (map). I tried to use getTotalCount but it returns 0 no matter if retrieved JSON contains features or no. Ext JS version 3.4.1. Code:

```
var store = new GeoExt.data.FeatureStore({
    layer: parcels,
    fields: [{
            name: "name"
        }
    ],
    proxy: new GeoExt.data.ProtocolProxy({
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "php/DB2GeoJSON.php",
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
        })
    })
});

var formPanel = new GeoExt.form.FormPanel({
    frame: true,
    title: "Search for parcels",
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: "php/DB2GeoJSON.php",
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    items: [{
            xtype: "textfield",
            name: "name",
            fieldLabel: "Parcel ID",
            value: ""
        }
    ],
    renderTo: "parcel_search",
    listeners: {
        actioncomplete: function (form, action) {
            json = Ext.util.JSON.decode(action.response.priv._object.responseText);
            features = action.response.features;
            store.loadData(features);
        }
    }
});

formPanel.addButton({
    text: "Search",
    handler: function () {
        this.search();
        var totalCount = store.getTotalCount();
        if (totalCount = "0") {
            Ext.Msg.alert("Alert", "No such parcel ID!");
        } else {
            new Ext.Window({
                title: "Search result"
                height: 400,
                width: 600,
                modal: true,
                layout: "border",
                draggable: false,
                resizable: false,
                closeAction: "hide",
                items: [{
                        region: "center",
                        id: "mappanel",
                        xtype: "gx_mappanel",
                        map: map,
                        split: true
                    }
                ]
            }).show();
        }
    },
    scope: formPanel,
    renderTo: "parcel_search"
})
```

Any help will be much appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem by getting number of features directly from JSON not the store populated afterwards and adding `json = Ext.util.JSON.decode(action.response.priv._object.responseText);` to be executed when search button is pressed. Also added search button to the initial definition of the form and defined some parts of the code as separate functions for better usability.

```
function mapDisplay() {
    var totalCount = json.totalCount;
    if (totalCount === 0) {
        Ext.Msg.alert("Alert", "No such parcel ID!");
    } else {
        new Ext.Window({
                title: "Search result",
                height: 400,
                width: 600,
                modal: true,
                layout: "border",
                draggable: false,
                resizable: false,
                closeAction: "hide",
                items: [{
                        region: "center",
                        id: "mappanel",
                        xtype: "gx_mappanel",
                        map: map,
                        split: true
                    }
                ]
            }).show();
    }
};

function searchParcel() {
    formPanel.search({
            success: function (form, action) {
                json = Ext.util.JSON.decode(action.response.priv._object.responseText);
                mapDisplay();
            }
        });
};

var formPanel = new GeoExt.form.FormPanel({
        frame: true,
        title: "Search for parcels",
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "php/parcel.php",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
            }),
        items: [{
                xtype: "textfield",
                name: "name",
                fieldLabel: "Parcel ID",
                value: ""
            }
        ],
        buttons: [{
                text: "Search",
                handler: searchParcel
            }
        ],
        renderTo: "parcel_search",
        listeners: {
            actioncomplete: function (form, action) {
                features = action.response.features;
                store.loadData(features);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is wrong:

```
 if (totalCount = "0") {
```

Should be:

```
if (totalCount === 0) {
```

---

`a=b` sets a equal b
`a==b` checks if a is somewhat equal b (`2=="2"` -> true)
`a==b` checks if a is equal b also the type of a and b (`2==="2"` -> false)

---

I'm guessing that `store.getTotalCount()` will return a number. If not your if statement should be:

```
if (totalCount === "0") {
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! Yes, it returns number so I changed to === and without quotes (yes, my JavaScript "knowledge" is very limited...), but it still always returns 0...

Answer (score 0):

I see you are calling `this.search()` which I could not find in your code. Presumably it is an async call to the server, which returns immediately, and before data has be loaded to the store. If I'm correct you will need to set a callback on your async call, or an event listener on the store load.

Comment: Yes, you are correct about `this.search()`. But how do I implement callback function on it? I know there are plenty of examples about callback functions, but when I need to adapt the idea to my code, I'm stuck...

Comment: So maybe post your search method, or better, create a fiddle

Comment: Managed to solve the problem, see my own answer. Also deleted intermediate comments containing references to the code not working yet.